# Submit button click event in .net using c#

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I want to code inside a button, but when I am double clicking the button it is opening the aspx code not c# code can anybody please help me

Comment: You should be able to cut/paste the event handler into your c# class.

Comment: But it is not showing the class, it's is only showing the asp code for designing